# Google MyMaps Limits

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am looking into using Google - MyMaps as a solution for displaying data.

What we require is the ability to put up a number of layers that we can plot on a Google map that we can share.
I have tested this with some sample data and it looks like it will work for us, however the MyMaps limits are a problem.

We are likely to have layers with features anywhere from 1,000 - 30,000

I have reviewed the supported data and limits [here](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3370982?hl=en&ref_topic=3024936)

What I would like to know is how can we get around these limits and what are the options?
I am open to any solutions or direction that needs to be taken to be able to make this happen.

Many thanks

Comment: you can't really cheat on google...

Comment: with (maps for work)[https://www.google.com/work/mapsearth/], you can get more quota on Google Maps. Not sure about my maps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to get around those limits, other than splitting into multiple layers. There are a couple of good alternatives though:

- Google Fusion Tables doesn't have this limit, but you might struggle to use multiple layers.
- QGIS - Open Source GIS software which allows for free web-hosting on their QGIS Cloud for projects up to 50MB.